# Why this error shows up Missing handler function for \"GET:/enteredUsers\" route. in fastify.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I am making an API to process fingerprint data coming from esp32. My code was working fine until I have one route when I added the second route it is continuously giving error and I am not getting it

**Error**

```
{"level":50,"time":1689522738157,"pid":12816,"hostname":"UMAR","err":
{"type":"FastifyError","message":"Missing handler function for \"GET:/enteredUsers\" 
route.","stack":"FastifyError: Missing handler function for \"GET:/enteredUsers\" route.\n    at 
Object.route (D:\\FYP\\fingerprint-API\\node_modules\\fastify\\lib\\route.js:198:13)\n    at 
Object.prepareRoute (D:\\FYP\\fingerprint-API\\node_modules\\fastify\\lib\\route.js:160:18)\n   
 at Object._get [as get] (D:\\FYP\\fingerprint-API\\node_modules\\fastify\\fastify.js:259:34)\n    at fingerprintRoutes (D:\\FYP\\fingerprint-API\\Routes\\fingerprintRoute.js:43:13)\n    at 
Plugin.exec (D:\\FYP\\fingerprint-API\\node_modules\\avvio\\plugin.js:130:19)\n    at 
Boot.loadPlugin (D:\\FYP\\fingerprint-API\\node_modules\\avvio\\plugin.js:272:10)\n    at 
processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)","code":"FST_ERR_ROUTE_MISSING_HANDLER","name":"FastifyE
rror","statusCode":500},"msg":"Missing handler function for \"GET:/enteredUsers\" route."}
```

**fingerprintcontroller.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const uri = process.env.URI;
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

const getFingerprintById =  async (req, res) => { 
    try {
        await client.connect();
        await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
        const database = client.db("Fyp");
        const collection = database.collection("Fingerprint_data");
        const collection2 = database.collection('UsersEntered');
        const query = { fingerprintId: req.params.id };
        const fingerprint = await collection.findOne(query);
        await collection2.insertOne(fingerprint);
        console.log(fingerprint)
        res.send(fingerprint);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

const enteredUsersData = async(req,res) => {
    try{
        await client.connect();
        
        const database = client.db("Fyp");
        const collection2 = database.collection('UsersEntered');
        const data = await collection2.find({}).toArray();
        console.log(data);

        res.send(data);
        
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    enteredUsersData,
    getFingerprintById,

};
```

**fingerprintRoute.js**

```
const FingerprintController = require('../Controllers/fingerprintController.js');

const getFingerprintById = {
    schema:{
        response:{
            200:{
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    fingerprintName: {type:'string'},
                    LicensePlate: {type:'string'},
                }
            }
        },
        params: { 
            type: 'object',
            additionalProperties: false,
            required: [ 'id' ],
            properties: { id: { type: 'string' }
        }
    }
    },
    handler: FingerprintController.getFingerprintById
}

const enteredUsersData = {
    schema:{
        response:{
            200:{
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    fingerprintName: {type:'string'},
                    LicensePlate: {type:'string'},
                }
            }
        },
        handler: FingerprintController.enteredUsersData
}
};


async function fingerprintRoutes(fastify,options,done){
    fastify.get('/enteredUsers',enteredUsersData);  // 
    fastify.get('/fingerprint/:id',getFingerprintById) // http://localhost:3000/fingerprint/1

    done();
}

module.exports = fingerprintRoutes;
```

**index.js**

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({logger:true})
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config();
const uri = process.env.URI;
const client  = new MongoClient(uri);

const fastifyCors = require('@fastify/cors');

fastify.register(fastifyCors, {
  // Set the CORS options
  origin: '*',
  methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
});



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

fastify.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send(' My fingerprint API is running')
})

fastify.register(require('./Routes/fingerprintRoute'))

async function run(){
    try {
        // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
        await client.connect();
        // Establish and verify connection
        await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
        // insert a document 
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");
      } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        await client.close();
      }
}

run().catch(console.dir);

fastify.listen({port: PORT},(err,address) => {
    if(err){
        fastify.log.error(err)
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT ${address}`)
})
```

Check these out. I am not getting the error because according to me everything is ok handlers are defined but its still giving error that there is missing handler function.

Comment: The handler property is inside the schema object in enteredUserData